# По щелчку на определенной ссылке вывести определенную строку из таблицы базы

Tags: php, mysql

Я новичок в PHP. У меня на главной странице 10 ссылок. Я хочу сделать универсальную страницу, которая бы появлялась после щелчка на любой из этих ссылок (ссылки однородные). Т.е. я не хочу для каждой писать свой файл html. Хочу одну страницу-шаблон и в ней бы только заменялось наполнение (наполнение ведется из определенной строки из таблицы базы) в зависимости от того, на какую ссылку щелкнули.

Как сказать так, чтобы по определенной строке брать свой id и выводить именно строку с этим id из таблицы его?

Буду очень благодарен любой помощи!!!))) Хотя бы в каком направлении двигаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На скорую руку так:

Ссылки

```
<a href="index.php?page=1">Ссылка 1</a>
<a href="index.php?page=2">Ссылка 2</a>
<a href="index.php?page=3">Ссылка 3</a>
<a href="index.php?page=4">Ссылка 4</a>
```

Вверху index.php

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1; //1-ссылка по-умолчанию
```

Ниже запрос к БД

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`=$page");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Вывод на странице

```
echo "<h2>".$data['title']."</h2>
<div>".$data['text']."</div>";
```

Comment: Спасибо большое DemoS!!!!!! буду пробовать!!! я тут впервые и наградил вас не той цифрой))) не туда нажал)))

Comment: Да не за что, пробуйте. На всякий случай, слева от ответа есть галочка, чтоб принять ответ. Если вам он подходит, то примите его, иначе он будет висеть у вас в непринятых. А людям, у кого много таких непринятых вопросов отвечают неохотно.

Comment: Demos, вы мне очень помогли) сейчас вот начал читать про репутацию на сайте и увидел, что я ее вам подпортил( извините пожалуйста... почему-то я вместо 10 вам 0 поставил... браузер глючит почему-то... простите и еще раз спасибо за ответ! что бы делали новички без таких людей как вы)

Comment: Да ничего страшного! Рад помочь! ))

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет `GET` запрос.
К каждой ссылке нужно дописать `?id=%идентификатор%`
А получить его на целевой странице можно из переменной `$_GET['id']`